# Objection.js ignoring validation of not recognized property type?

Tags: javascript, validation, ajv, objection.js

Im using this jsonSchema in my Objection model:

```
  static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: 'object',
      required: ['firstName', 'lastName'],

      properties: {
        id: { type: 'integer' },
        parentId: { type: ['integer', 'null'] },
        firstName: { type: 'string', minLength: 1, maxLength: 255 },
        lastName: { type: 'string', minLength: 1, maxLength: 255 },
        date: {type: 'unexisting-type'},
        age: { type: 'number' },
      }
    };
  }
```

You can see **date** is a type not recognized by AJV validation (that is used by Objection.js). However, the Insert operation return success when inserting following data:

```
{
    "firstName":"sample",
    "lastName":"sample",
    "date":"2018-12-21 10:20"
}
```

Why AJV is not returning a validation error on schema creation?

I tested in a minimal JSFiddle example and it does return an error (AJV v6.6.2)
https://jsfiddle.net/ads80y5j/

Im using Objection v1.4.0 (uses AJV  v^6.1.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objection itself is passing Ajv the option of turning off the validation of the schema, so no errors will be throwed at Ajv schema compile time.

For now, Objection v1 will maintain this behaviour, since its a breaking change. Could be added in v2.

https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/issues/1182

Answer (score 1):

I do get the following exception when running the code below. *(If I wrap the code in your JSFiddle, I get a similar result too.)*

> schema is invalid: data.properties['date'].type should be equal to one of the allowed values, data.properties['date'].type should be array, data.properties['date'].type should match some schema in anyOf

```js
var ajv = new Ajv({
  allErrors: true
});

var schema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    date: {
      type: 'unexisting-type'
    }
  }
};

try {
  var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/6.6.2/ajv.min.js"></script>
```

Could it be that somewhere in your code, you silently swallow the exception or that you have somehow turned off the validation of the schema itself?

From the documentation for [`compile`](https://ajv.js.org/#api):

> The schema passed to this method will be validated against meta-schema unless validateSchema option is false. If schema is invalid, an error will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think Objection is swallowing the error or using the option you mention. I added an unexisting validation property and I still dont get any error: `date: {type: 'unexisting-type', unexistingProperty: 'unexisting-property'}`.
Im testing in this example: https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/blob/master/examples/express-es6/models/Person.js (only added the 'date' property, nothing else)